# Playing Local Music File from Music Directory in Windows Store apps HTML-JavaScript using Audio-tag

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have audio tag in my Windows Store application and I want to play music from Music Directory of the Device.

Following is the src I am setting for Audio Tag

```
audioTag.src = "file:///C:/Users/Ashwin/Music/JiveHD Songs/Yi Qie Wei Liao Ai.mp3"
```

But It audioTag onError event is raised.
Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive it's because you don't have access to user's music library. You need to add music library decleration in app capabalities. More about App Capabilities you can read at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx